# Removing text after a specific delimeter

Tags: linux

I extract all the links from a specific webpage using lynx.

```
lynx -dump http://www.example.com/videos | awk '/http/"{print $2}"' >> links.txt
```

It give the following output:

```
http://www.example.com/home/
http://www.example.com/contact/
http://www.example.com/videos/
..
..
..
..
http://www.example.com/video/1001/The-title-of-video
http://www.example.com/video/1002/The-title-of-video
http://www.example.com/video/1003/The-title-of-video
http://www.example.com/video/1004/The-title-of-video
..so on
```

I want to do following things.

1. Output only those links which contains /video/
2. remove the title in the end of the link http://www.example.com/video/1001/<strike>The-title-of-video</strike> should output only http://www.example.com/video/1001/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grep` to filter the output, `sed` to remove the title:

```
lynx -dump http://www.example.com/videos | grep /video/ | sed 's=/[^/]*$=='
```

Comment: great ! but output is in numbered format.. how to remove numbering.

Comment: The output you pasted is not numbered. You can use `sed` to remove the numbers hopefully, or maybe even `cut`. Show the exact output.